# What is the most efficient to find correlation coefficients of time series contained in large matrices using c++?

Tags: c++, time-series, correlation

I am working with a matrices containing satellite vegetation data of the entire United States with a 250m resolution so each matrix is 212,029,488 pixels and I have a matrix for each year in the 17 year span I'm studying.
My goal is to calculate correlation coefficients for each pixel with all surrounding pixels (within a radius of 20 pixels or 5km) and assign the value of the average of all those correlation coefficients to the each focal pixel. (See attached image for clarification)

The obvious approach is to go pixel by pixel starting in [1,1] calculating the correlation coefficient for each surrounding pixel finding the average, then repeating this process x many times for each pixel in the matrix.

The problem with that approach is I find it to be incredibly clunky and redundant because it leads to identical calculations having to be performed many times. For example - when finding the correlation coefficients for pixel @ [1,1] the coefficient with [1,2] is performed once and then when the coefficients for pixel [1,2] are performed the aforementioned correlation has to be performed again - and an increasing amount of repeated calculations are performed for each new focal pixel being calculated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an more efficient approach:

1. Calculate the correlation between each pixel, which would yield a MNxMN correlation matrix
2. Because we don't need every correlation, only perform the calculations for those which are in range of a window => Use a MNxMN **sparse** matrix to store the results
3. Now for each entry in the original matrix, calculate the average. If you choose your indices of the MNxMN matrix carefully it might be possible to formulate this operation as convolution on the MNxMN correlation matrix.